# How to allow special characters in Rewrite_Map?

Tags: apache, apache2, url-shortener

Here is the config I am using

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteMap shortlinks txt:/var/www/html/s.overhash.net/public_html/shortlinks.txt
RewriteRule ^/(.+)$ ${shortlinks:$1} [R=temp,L]
```

My txt document looks something like this:

```
9H40o https://osyrisrblx.github.io/playground/#code/HYUw7gBAggTjCGBPAPMArgWwEYhgPgAoBKAOhhABM0BjEAggB3IDcAaCatOEYAFyIC8eJiGYBqAZ258iQA
```

However, upon going to my site (http://s.overhash.net/9H40o), it replaces the `#` with %23, making the URL this:

```
https://osyrisrblx.github.io/playground/%23code/HYUw7gBAggTjCGBPAPMArgWwEYhgPgAoBKAOhhABM0BjEAggB3IDcAaCatOEYAFyIC8eJiGYBqAZ258iQA
```

(which isn't valid)

How would I go about ensuring the `#` remains?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a rewrite map issue, it's the way rewrite rules work.
By default, special chars will be escaped.

Use the `NE` flag in your rewriterule if you don't want that to happen:

`RewriteRule ^/(.+)$ ${shortlinks:$1} [NE,R=temp,L]`

More details on https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_ne