Apache RewriteMap with URLs containing special characters doesn't work
I am using RewriteMap directive inside Apache config. It does not work if URL contains special characters, but for URLs without special characters it works fine.
OK
/test/example /test-example1

Not OK
/test/example%C2%A0test /
/%20.html /test
/test%C3%A3o/test%C2%A0example%C3%Bexample /test

Apache config part
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteMap redirects dbm=db:/etc/httpd/conf.d/test.db
  RewriteCond ${redirects:$1} !=""
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ${redirects:$1} [redirect=permanent,last]

  RewriteCond ${redirects:$1} !=""
  RewriteRule ^(.*)\/$ ${redirects:$1} [redirect=permanent,last]



And what entries does the rewrite map contain, that are supposed to match those URLs? You might perhaps need to set the NE flag, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/58618278/1427878

Rewrite map contain these lines
/test/example%C2%A0test /
/%20.html /test
/test%C3%A3o/test%C2%A0example%C3%Bexample /test
/test/example /test-example1

Don't think that NE flag can help here

Yeah, you might rather need to go into the other direction then - B, or perhaps BNP flag, https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_bnp
